# Postfix always_bcc when using an external content filter

Tags: routes, smtp, postfix-mta

I use the postfix `header_checks` with `FILTER` commands to route emails to different other internal servers based on headers. Like this:

```
/^header-A/   FILTER smtp:[192.168.0.1]
/^header-B/   FILTER smtp:[192.168.0.2]
```

How can I now send a copy of **all** emails to another third server, e.g. 192.168.0.3?

I thought about using `always_bcc` but this just adds an additional recipient while the emails are still just sent to the two servers 192.168.0.1/2.